# C#: Method Invocation Details

Tags: c#

I have a website developed using C#. I want to see the caller of a method i.e, which method/event handler calls my method.

Suppose there is a button click. I would like to see it as follows

```
btnClick  BusinessLayerClass.SaveDocs(int docID, string docType) DataAccessLayerClass.Update()

btnClick  BusinessLayerClass.SaveDocs(int docID, string docType) DataAccessLayerClass.Increase()
```

Is it possible to see such a stack information? Please advise..

**Note**: All projects are added as dlls. There is no services like WCF.

Comment: Checking the stack trace in your application is almost always a bad design choice. It's meant for debugging, and nothing more. May we know **why** you want to see it?

Comment: @Vilx-: There ARE valid reasons for getting a stacktrace.

Comment: @leppie There are seldom valid reasons for getting a stacktrace

Comment: @leppie - that's why the word "almost". There's always an exception. Though in this case I've yet to come upon one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Environment.StackTrace  can be used

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
        StackFrame[] fram = st.GetFrames();

        foreach (StackFrame sf in fram)
        {
            sf.GetFileColumnNumber();
            sf.GetFileLineNumber();
            sf.GetFileName();
            sf.GetILOffset();
            sf.GetMethod();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. However, how do I know the order of method calls? (like SaveDocs called Update() ? )

Comment: I guess the array returned by GetFrames() method maintains the order of methods called. In the above code, first or last frame should be the one that called your method. Just play around a bit until you figure it out.